# Can Android v2.3 Play MP4 files?

Tags: android

I have an MP4 file that I play with the MediaPlayer example in API demos on the emulator. Only the sound is played. No video. Why would this be and how do i get it to play?

BTW: .3gp files to play both audio and video in the same example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The supported media formats are listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html . Make sure your mp4 file uses the right format (H.264 AVC or H.263).

Comment: Thanks. I have that list. What tool can I use to check the format of the MP4 that I am attempting to play?

Comment: Run the file in Quicktime... there's a property inspector from one of the menu items that will show all the information of that file.